# Run command through Batch file

Tags: svn, batch-file, cmd, command

I want to take backup of Visual SVN via command promt and want to execute these commands via a batch file and the file name should be the current date and time.

My Code is

```
 @echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('date /T') do set datestr=%%a
start cmd.exe /C "svnadmin dump D:\Repositories\MyProjects > D:\Repositories\MyProjects\%datestr%.bak"
```

please help

Comment: what do you get if you echo %datestr%?

Comment: Matt Williamson command did execute correctly

Comment: add CALL before start and run the batch file

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions
    set "_dir=D:\Repositories\MyProjects"
    svnadmin dump "%_dir%" > "%_dir%\%date:/=%.bak"
    endlocal
```

No need for `date /t`, %date% environment variable return the same value. And if date contains slashes, it need to be replaced/deleted.

Comment: your code created a file but command didnt run correctly. it created a file 19112013.bak of 0 byte .i need to run the command to create a complete backup file.

Comment: I've no access to Visual SVN to try. Batch file sintax is correct, but don't know about svnadmin. From documentation "`PATH-TO-SVN\svnadmin dump PATH-TO-REPO > PATH-TO-DUMP`" it seems correct, but there is a note "`Repository dump should be created using the svnadmin utility from the corresponding Subversion installation used to create this repository.`" So, maybe, a cd to correct directory may be needed.

Comment: if i write command in qoutes then it work but in qoutes %date% is used as a string "%date%"                                          Like "svnadmin dump D:\Repositories\MyProjects > D:\Repositories\MyProjects\%datestr%.bak"

Comment: Downloaded svn, created repository, and tested batch code in answer. As is (changed path to repository dir). No cmd /c, no aditional quotes. If svn bin directory is in path, or if call to svnadmin includes the full path to executable, it works. Not sure what your problem with quotes is.

Comment: i hav executed your code and it created a file,but command didnt execute to take complete backup.

Comment: @ihsanchani: Have you checked what is inside of the generated file?

Comment: @ihsanchani: Just to test, if you change in batch file the svnadmin line to `svnadmin dump "d:\Repositories\MyProjects" > "d:\Repositories\MyProjects\20131120.bak"` does it work?

Comment: no same issue i think this code is correct but we have to add some extra line to do the complete task